# MATLAB Class Method Approach

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods

I have a class that populates properties which are time-series parameters. The parameters time unit can be seconds of the day (SOD) or run time (RT). I also have methods which plot these parameters. I am looking for the best way to give the user the option to be able to plot in either SOD or RT. Here is what my class looks like:

```
properties:
   AC_Voltage
   DC_Voltage
   TimeSOD
   TimeRT
end

methods:
   function me = DataViewer()
   % sets the properties

   function CalculateSOD(me)
   function CalculateRT(me)
   function PlotACVoltage(me)
   function PlotDCVoltage(me)
end
```

The class is passed as a field to a GUIDE GUI handle and a button exists for each plot method. What I'd like to do is for example call PlotACVoltage which plots that parameter against SOD, then have the option to call it again and plot it in RT, and have the freedom to be able to switch back and forth. What methods/properties should I setup in support of this? Thanks.

Comment: What if you save the SOD that corresponds to RT==0, and just convert between them using summation or subtraction? Even if the conversion is more complicated (e.g. offset + scale), switching between them seems like just changing `xticklabel`....

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: What is the difference between two plots with different time scales? Does switching between the two time scales require any actions other than simply changing what's _written_ below the `x` axis (values of the tick marks and the axis title)?

Comment: No difference. I guess you are implying I should just change the values of the tick marks?